# Ionic not able to import global library

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, webpack

I created a pure Javascript library (no dependency on other frameworks like Angular or Ionic) which is bundled using Webpack. It is bundled so all functionality is exported to the window object.

Now I want to use this library in an Ionic app. In my code I import the library like this:

```
import * as MyLibrary from "my-library"
```

Which appears to work as my code editor recognizes the import (and even fetches the Typescript typings). When building the project with `ionic build` no compilation errors show up.

However when I run the project in my browser I run into a problem. When I log the imported library it shows an empty object without any of the exported classes and methods.

```
import * as MyLibrary from "my-library"
console.log(MyLibrary); // This results in an empty object e.g. {}
```

Effectively this causes all my code to fail since it tries to call methods on an empty object.

However when I type `MyLibrary` in the Chrome Debugger console it does show the library was loaded.

Is Ionic unable to load these kind of global libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `my-library` module generated by Webpack does not have any exports but creates a `MyLibrary` global variable on the window when it loads.  If that's the case, then instead of importing `MyLibrary` from the module (and shadowing the global variable), you should just import the module for its side effect, and then use the `MyLibrary` global variable:

```
import "my-library"
console.log(MyLibrary);  // This should show you the same thing you saw in the Chrome console.
```

This will likely mess up your type information.  If TypeScript currently thinks the module is declared under the name `my-library`, then add the following dance to a new `.d.ts` file in your project to alias the module to the global `MyLibrary` variable:

```
declare module "dummy" {
  import * as MyLibrary_ from "my-library";
  global {
    namespace Dummy {
      export import MyLibrary = MyLibrary_;
    }
  }
}
import MyLibrary = Dummy.MyLibrary;
```

(See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14051#issuecomment-367417846) for background.)

Instead of using the above workarounds, it might be less confusing to change how `my-library` is bundled so that it has exports instead of defining a global variable.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your answer. I'll try your suggestion and also investigate bundling this library so it properly exports. Will report back.

Comment: I changed the webpack `libraryTarget` to umd instead of a global export to the window object. Now it it correctly imported by Ionic. Thanks for the help!